# Magento 2 How to disable Postal/Zip code validation from admin while edit customer?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, form-validation, zipcode

I am facing a strange issue while adding Customer, I had filled all the fields in the customer form including Zipcode but still, I am getting error

> "Zip/Postal Code" is a required value.

[image]

In my form all fields are field. I tried to remove this error by making postal code field optional from Magento configuration:

> Store -> General -> Zip/Postal Code is Optional for

but no luck.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vendor class or module has been changed,
Run this command:

```
composer update
```

then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove cache:

```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I remove and flushed cache multiple times, not fix :(